# JQuery .focus() not work in .blur() event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have used below code but it not work in firefox for focus textbox in .blur() event using JQuery

```
    $("#txtfname").focus(function () {
        if ($("#txtfname").val() == "" && $("#txtfname").val().length >= 2) {
            $("#fnamemsg").hide();
        }
    });

    $("#txtfname").blur(function () {
        if ($("#txtfname").val() != "" && $("#txtfname").val().length < 2) {
            $("#fnamemsg").show();
            $("#fnamemsg").html("Minimum 5 character");
            $("#txtfname").focus();
        }
        else { $("#fnamemsg").hide(); }
    });
```

Comment: So how exactly does the value equal an empty string, and at the same time have a length over 2 characters, that's a real conundrum ?

Comment: Is that supposed to work on other browsers than FF, really?!

Comment: `$("#txtfname").val() == "" && $("#txtfname").val().length >= 2`??? This is just silly. Will return false every single time

Comment: yes as per requirement i have applied my code

Comment: @NikunjDesai What is the purpose of checking for a condition which will always returns false?

Comment: Might as well be saying `if (false) {}`

Comment: try `if ($("#txtfname").val().length >= 2)` and then on blur... `if ($("#txtfname").val().length < 2)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    $("#txtfname").focus(function () {
     //Check if value is blank or not
     if ($("#txtfname").val() === "" && $("#txtfname").val().length >= 2) {
         $("#fnamemsg").hide(); // Hide message
     }
 });

var element = document.getElementById('txtfname');
 element.focus();
 element.onblur = function () {
     if (element.value !== "" && element.value.length < 2) {
         $("#fnamemsg").show();
         $("#fnamemsg").html("* Firstname required 2 character");
         setTimeout(function () {
             element.focus();
         }, 0);
     } else {
         $("#fnamemsg").hide();
     }
 };
```

Comment: @NikunjDesai But could you explain what is the expected behaviour? What is the purpose of your jsfiddle?

Comment: He wants to validate that #txtfname is 5 or more characters as seen in the message... however he lists 2 as the length which is a bit confusing to begin with. I've posted what I believe is the answer he is looking for

Comment: @zgr024 That's ok but as he posted it as answer, i believe this is what he is looking for but for sure doesn't make any sense

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't disagree... but we are here to help in any way we can, even if it means making sense of something that is illogical

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are messed up and your message doesn't match your conditions either.
The following will hide the message on focus if the value of #txtfname is 5 or more characters and show the message on blur if its less than 5 characters.

```
$("#txtfname").focus(function () {
    if ($("#txtfname").val().length >= 5) {
        $("#fnamemsg").hide();
    }
});

$("#txtfname").blur(function () {
    if ($("#txtfname").val().length < 5) {
        $("#fnamemsg").show();
        $("#fnamemsg").html("Minimum 5 characters"); 
        $("#txtfname").focus();
    }
    else { $("#fnamemsg").hide(); }
});
```

Comment: `"Minimum 5 characters"` seeing this, this answer makes more sense than the OP's one for sure